# Error while knitting an Rmd file: error in eval(x, envir = envir): argument is missing, with no default

Tags: error-handling, knitr

I get an error while trying to knit an Rmd file on Rstudio.
It's quite weird since I **export that file successfully in html file one day before I tried to revise the Rmd file a little.** I'm sure that I did not revise the code chunk.

The errors show as below:
**error in eval(x, envir = envir): argument is missing, with no default
Calls:  ... eval_lang -> in_put_dir -> in_dir -> eval -> eval
Execution halted.**

[Click to see screenshot of the error in Rmd file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmFTf.jpg)

The code chunk can work well in the Rmd file and just shows errors when I knitted the file.

One more note that I have to install XQuartz to my macbook before I can knit the Rmd file in my laptop. And now the XQuartz show this message too. Is there any relation between the error and the XQuartz notification?
[Click to see XQuartz notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9whEq.jpg)

Is there is way to resole this error?

Comment: I think the missing parameter might be missing `TRUE` in the header of the code chunk, where it says `r echo=`

Comment: Thank u. I've just recognized it too lol